# I can not do this query without nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three attributes (identificator, id_law, surname, vote).
Vote can take three values: positive, against or abstained.

I can not do this query:
you want to know every law as there are votes in positive, against and abstentions.

The select must be unique and are not allowed nested select

Comment: Your question is quite vague as asked.  Remember, people looking at the question have no idea what you are doing, except for the information you provide.  Sample data, desired results, table structures, and an example query definitely help clarify questions.

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data? It may help us understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table house_law
(   -- the proposed up for vote
law_id varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
descr varchar(255)
);

insert house_law (law_id,descr) values ('HR-109B','Forbid driving near turtles');

create table house_rep
(   -- a session is say Monday to Friday, captures a start date
rep_id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
fullname varchar(80) not null,
party varchar(80)
);

insert house_rep (rep_id,fullname,party) values (1001,'Thomas Jefferson','Whig');
insert house_rep (rep_id,fullname,party) values (800,'fred','Abstain Party');
insert house_rep (rep_id,fullname,party) values (700,'stan','Abstain Party');

create table votes_cast
(law_id varchar(50) not null,
rep_id int not null,
the_vote varchar(20) -- for, against, abstain
);

insert votes_cast (law_id,rep_id,the_vote) values ('HR-109B',1001,'against');
insert votes_cast (law_id,rep_id,the_vote) values ('HR-109B',800,'abstain');
insert votes_cast (law_id,rep_id,the_vote) values ('HR-109B',700,'abstain');

-- get the results

select l.law_id,
l.descr,
sum(case when v.the_vote='for' then 1 else 0 end) for_votes,
sum(case when v.the_vote='against' then 1 else 0 end) against_votes,
sum(case when v.the_vote='abstain' then 1 else 0 end) abstain_votes
from house_law l
join votes_cast v
on v.law_id=l.law_id
group by l.law_id -- or a where close for 1 law in particular
```

**output**:
id  |   descr  | votes_for | against | abstain

HR-109B Forbid driving near turtles 0   1   2